# How make scroll visible for textarea on mobile devices

Tags: css, reactjs, textarea

When I try to scroll textarea using phone, I can't see the scroll, I tries many ways to
enable it but it still not visible, Is there any way to show scroll for textarea when using mobile device?

**My code:**

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <textarea className="test" />
    </div>
  );
}


 .test {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.test::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

.test::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.test::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

@media (pointer: coarse) {
  .test {
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    scrollbar-color: red red;
  }
}
```

**Codesandbox**: ( You can visit this link with you phone and check, scroll is non visible )
https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-framework-pezr67?file=/src/App.js:0-147

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question right, the solution is that you just change

> overflow: auto

to

> overflow: scroll

on line 8